# why checkbox is not checked in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form, final-form

I am trying to implement `Auto complete` having `checkbox`.

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete
[image]

but when I am implementing same component in `final-form` I am not able to checked my option why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-breeze-hv58o

```
<Autocomplete
      {...rest}
      multiple={multiple}
      disableCloseOnSelect={true}
      options={
        multiple
          ? maxReached
            ? []
            : options.filter(option => !value.includes(option.value))
          : options
      }
      defaultValue={
        multiple
          ? options.filter(option => value.includes(option.value))
          : options.find(option => option.value === value)
      }
      onChange={
        multiple
          ? (_e, values) => {
              setMaxReached(value.length >= max - 1);
              onChange(values.map(option => option.value));
            }
          : (_e, option) => onChange(option.value)
      }
      getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
      noOptionsText={
        maxReached
          ? formatMessage({ id: "components.autocomplete.max" }, { max })
          : formatMessage({ id: "components.autocomplete.no" })
      }
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.label}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...restInput}
          label={label}
          placeholder={placeholder || ""}
          helperText={
            hasError ? formatMessage({ id: error }, { label }) : helperText
          }
          error={hasError}
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: What is the type of the value `selected`? Is it a boolean?

Comment: i think yes... i just copy any paste from here https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete

Comment: You should just try hard coding the value to start to see if that is the issue. Just replace `selected` with `true` and then let's go from there.

Comment: Also the value `selected` needs to come from some sort of state, whether it's component state or if you're using Redux.

Comment: yes it is boolean..`issue is this function not called again renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon` .  when user checked any item

Comment: first time it called second time after selection not callled

Comment: Ok I know the issue, you haven't set any state variables to hold the selected state. I'll have a solution for you in a moment, I'll post the link to the codesandbox.

Comment: Ok that wasn't the issue, the issue is you're `onChange` handler.

Comment: If you comment out the entire `onChange` you will see it operate correctly.

Comment: but then my value is not set in form

Comment: see `auto` array is blank {
  "stooge": "larry",
  "employed": false,
  "auto": []
}

Comment: I see, hmm interesting. Initially I think since you're onChange handler makes an update to state, it then calls a rerender which closes the dropdown. Sill trying to figure out the exact issue though.

Comment: Do you want the dropdown to close? Also should all the items remain in the dropdown even if they're selected?

Comment: no ..yes all item in dropdown

Comment: sorry for late repley

Comment: No problem, it's hard to know what that `onChange` from the input actually does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206325/discussion-between-user944513-and-nicholas-porter).

Comment: any update of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issues with your code ([fixed version](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-swirles-y9bcj)):

1. You are calling `onChange` that makes `React-Final-Form` re-render, which leads for `Autocomplete` component to re-render, and remove the select state. To fix this, you will have to use `getOptionSelected` option.

```
getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
    return option.value === value.value;
}}
options={ 
    options
}
onChange={(_e, values) => {
    onChange(values);
}
```

2. You are filtering `options` based to `Autocomplete` component, so selected option gets filtered out.
   so from this:

```
options={
  multiple
  ? maxReached
  ? []
  : options.filter(option => !value.includes(option.value))
  : options
}
```

To

```
options={
   options
}
```

Comment: [MUI-RFF](https://github.com/lookfirst/mui-rff) is a reusable component library for Material UI + React Final Form, which includes the Autocomplete component. This excellent answer has been copied into the example app. Thanks!

Comment: @JonStevens, thanks for your sweet words :). I am glad to help.